Problem with bundler not installing gems for different platforms
I use a Mac locally and in my Gemfile.lock, I have both platforms:
PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin-23
  x86_64-linux

So when I bundle install I get nokogiri-1.16.7-arm64-darwin.gem in my Rails app's vendor/cache. But I'd also expect to see x86_64-linux version but I am not seeing it.
Is there a way I can force bundle to download the Linux version in addition to the arm version? I'm not sure why the PLATFORMS directive is being ignored.

bundle package --all platforms might help here.

Thx @Unixmonkey that did it (with a dash in --all-platforms)!

Run bundle package --all-platforms
